# How to print results derived from a loop in scrapy shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm very much new to work with scrapy shell. I searched a lot but could not find out what is the print command in scrapy shell. If you take a look the bellow scripts, you can understand what I meant.

```
scrapy shell http://quotes.toscrape.com/ --nolog
for item in response.css(".author"):
    author_name = item.css("::text").extract_first()
    print(author_name)   # What should be the command to print the `author_name`.
```

So, if anybody helps me as to how I can print results in scrapy shell, I'would be grateful to him. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `pprint`? 
`from pprint import pprint` and then `pprint(author_name)`

Comment: Yep, i tried. pprint is not working.

Comment: It works for me. Which version of python and Scrapy are you using? Are you sure that `author_name` is not None in your case?

Comment: Works for me as well. Is your intent to just print it on screen, right?

Comment: Python 3.5 and scrapy 1.4

Comment: @ Tomáš Linhart , yes that is.

Comment: @ Roman Mindlin, author name is not none. I can see results if i take out for loop and just use `extract()` or `extract_first()`. However, my intention is to find results derived from a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: Could you, please, test with just `print(1)` and with `type(author_name)`?

Comment: Please, press Enter one more time and let me see result )

Comment: @Roman Mindlin, please post it as an answer. Pressing enter twice after using `pprint(author_name)` I got the result. Thanks for the invaluable suggestion.

Comment: This is the link to the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n5ki0hhr0s1dks/final_result.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type multiple lines expression in the interactive shell you should press Enter twice after last line.

Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/381719/how-do-i-write-code-of-more-than-1-line-in-the-python-interpreter) to get more information about continuation lines.

Comment: Thanks Roman Mindlin, for being with me throughout the time. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might know this already but for those who don't, this may help:

```
scrapy shell http://quotes.toscrape.com/ --nolog
for item in response.css(".author"):
    item.css("::text").extract_first()
```

If you run the above code, without the print statement, this would still work give you extracted author names.